# If $Z \perp X | V$ does it follow that $Y \perp X | V \implies Y \perp X | V,Z$?

Tags: conditional-expectation, independence

Given random variables $(Y,X,Z,V)$ and letting $\perp$ denote independence I want to show that if $Z \perp X | V$, then
$$
Y \perp X | V \implies Y \perp X | V,Z.
$$
My current attempt is
$$
F_{Y|X,V,Z}(y) = \mathbb{E}(1(Y \leq y) | X,V,Z) = \mathbb{E}(1(Y \leq y) | V,Z) = F_{Y|V,Z}(y), 
$$
but i cannot mathematically justify the second equality. The intuition is that if knowing $V$, $X$ does not tell me anything about $Y$, then conditioning also on $Z$ which is independent of $X$ given $V$ should not make $X$ anymore relevant... also assuming that a Lebesgue pdf exist, integrating with respect to $f_{Y|X,V,Z}$ is the same as integrating with respect to $f_{Y|V,Z}$ since
$$
f_{Y|X,V,Z} = \frac{f_{Y,X,Z|V}}{f_{X,Z|V}} = \frac{f_{Y,Z|V}f_{X|V}}{f_{X|V}f_{Z|V}} = f_{Y|V,Z}.
$$
If lebesgue pdfs exist this should be enough to prove it, but i would like to prove it just by using properties of conditional expectations, is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Could you clarify the definition of $Y \perp X | V$?

Comment: It means that $Y$ and $X$ are independent random variables given $V$.  In formulas, $P(Y|X,V) = P(Y|V)$ or $P(X|Y,V) = P(X|V)$ or $P(X$ and $Y|V) = P(X|V)\cdot P(Y|V)$

Comment: @JRT I don't think it holds, because of the second equality on

$f_{Y|X,V,Z} = \frac{f_{Y,X,Z|V}}{f_{X,Z|V}} = \frac{f_{Y,Z|V}f_{X|V}}{f_{X|V}f_{Z|V}} = f_{Y|V,Z}$

should not hold.

Comment: @Dole why do you think it should not hold? my reasoning is that: $Y \perp X | V$ and $Z \perp X | V \implies X \perp Y,Z | V$ which implies the second equality

Comment: @JRT That does not appear correct. The problem is that just because $X \perp Z$ and $Y \perp Z$ does not mean that $X,Y \perp Z$ mutually.

Comment: @Dole I think you are right. I guess I should work on a counterexample then, thanks